# Movie about meteor exuding liquid that zombifies people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Old movie, low budget, in colour, could be TV movie. It was before the Sunny Delight craze (which reminded me of this) so 90s at the latest.

A meteorite lands in America. It is found quickly and as it cools it exudes a thick creamy liquid, possibly pink. Some fool-hardy by-stander actually tastes it and finds it delicious.

Next thing we know, a (sinister) local company starts bottling it and selling it as a drink. It becomes wildly popular. However...

Once ingested the goo takes over the drinkers' bodies and they turn into zombie-like creatures. Probably it's an alien attack in progress.

As per usual only one man notices that something is up and tries to stop it, a la David Vincent in The Invaders.

I don't remember how he does it but he manages to save humanity.

Have a feeling lead was familiar to me from TV but don't remember who.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your description is very similar to [The Stuff, 1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stuff).  The [cast](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090094/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm) had some serious talent.

> Several quarry workers discover a white cream-like alien substance
> bubbling out of the ground. These workers find it to be sweet and
> addictive. Later, the substance, marketed as "The Stuff", is being
> sold to the general public in containers like ice cream. It is
> marketed as having no calories and as being sweet, creamy, and
> filling. The Stuff quickly becomes a nationwide craze and drastically
> hurts the sales of ice cream.
>
> Former FBI agent turned industrial saboteur David "Mo" Rutherford is
> hired by the leaders of the suffering ice cream industry, as well as
> junk food mogul Charles W. "Chocolate Chip Charlie" Hobbs, to find out
> exactly what The Stuff is and destroy it.
>
> Under their commissions, Rutherford conducts an investigation into The
> Stuff. His efforts reveal, to his initial horror, that the craze for
> the dessert is far deadlier than anyone had believed: The Stuff is
> actually a living, parasitic, and possibly sentient organism that
> gradually takes over the brain; it then mutates those who eat it into
> bizarre zombie-like creatures, before consuming them from the inside
> and leaving them empty shells of their former selves.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193899/23243

Comment: Ah yes, Michael Moriarty. I'd seen him in Law & Order on UK TV before I saw this film. Definitely the right answer. Thanks.